# Django Connect To MySql DB Table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to Make an auth system without using the Django user.authenticate system because I want to make 2 seperate Login Systems. 1 For the IT & Web Development Dept. and another 1 for the general users. So I'm using the same MySql Database and the Auth_user for my IT dept. and I created a accounts app which I want to use the accounts_benutzer (users in german) table.

I can add thanks to the app system users etc. over the Admin Panel but I want that the users which are registered by an IT Dept User log in on the Main Page with the given username and password

### My views/models/template is like:

accounts/models.py:

```
class Benutzer(models.Model):
 
regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{7,15}$')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    passwort = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
....
```

---

accounts/views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from .models import Benutzer

def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['name']
        passwort = request.POST['passwort']

        if (username == Benutzer.name) and (passwort == Benutzer.passwort):
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Falsche Zugangs Daten!')
            return redirect('/accounts/login')

    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

---

login.html:

```
{% load static %}
<form action="login" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <p>Benutzername: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Benutzer Name"></p>
        <p>Passwort: <input type="password" name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Bestaetigen">-<input type="reset" value="Löschen">
    </form>
    <div>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <h3>{{message}}</h3>
        {% endfor %}
```

I know it doesn't make sense to use Benutzer.user or Benutzer.passwort but thats the point which I am asking. How Can I manage to compare the data which I get from the website with the data on my MySQL table accounts_benutzer to give the user access?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "2 seperate Login Systems"? I can't see any reason why django's built in authentication system wouldn't work for staff & general users. Your database connection information should live in `settings.py` and enable you to use the database.

Comment: 1) Educational experience
2) Doing something out of the box
3) Giving the End-User the choice of seperate Staff & General Users ( Make a better feel when the end-user can put himself/herself in other categories)(Just a capitalist thought tho)
And my database connection works I can put inside new stuff over the Administration site . I just want to make a authorization without the build in because I want a 2nd log in for normal users and I don't want the normal user database mixed with my Admin user Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are other ways, but this should work.

```
def login(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['name']
    passwort = request.POST['passwort']

    B_user = Benutzer.objects.filter(name=username).first()

    if B_user and B_user.passwort == passwort:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.info(request,'Falsche Zugangs Daten!')
        return redirect('/accounts/login')

else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: Thanks mate this was actually very simple and works for this situation. I really appreciate it.